# angular variables inside ng-includes do not minify

Tags: angularjs

I have some ng-includes like this

```
<ng-include src="'/path/to/template'+ my.variable +'.html'"></ng-include>
```

when i minify the code with grunt the variables do not work.  if i take out the variables and hard code the path it works.

any idea why or how it can be fixed?

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error with the minified version? How is your "my.variable" defined. Please check if there is any hoisting or Temporal dead zone issues with the variable. Just a pointer . May not be the actual issue. Please share the complete code so that we can help you better.

Comment: fixed. i was minifing the controllers with the wrong order.